# How do I control background music from app?

Tags: c#, c++, windows-phone-8

I have a `c#/xaml` app. I'd like to play instruction sounds, but if the user is playing background music, I'd like to mute it, or lower the volume temporarily while the sounds are being played.

Currently, I'm using `xaudio2` to play my audio in C++, and using some delegates to make calls into C# where I'm using the `MediaPlayer` class from the `xna framework` to mute the background media.

However, after pausing the music, when I go to play my instruction through `xaudio2`, I get `System.InvalidOperationException` exception from the `xna` framework. If I comment out the line for playing the sound, there is no exception.

I suppose it's worth noting that this is not happening on the UI thread...

Am I going about this the right way? I can't find any links to information on how to accomplish this - I'm grasping at straws.

Comment: I think doing this is highly inadvisable. If I am playing music on my phone, the **last** thing I want an app to do is mess with it in *any* way, including playing sounds on top of it. I expect applications that I use when music is already playing to be *silent*. Any that violate this inspire instant irritation, and if they cannot be quickly and easily silenced (and note they will likely be silenced forever at this point) then **they get uninstalled immediately**. I own my phone. Not the application. I highly recommend you wait for the user to opt in to any sound behavior like this.

Comment: Okay - then if I let the user opt into this behavior, what would be the correct way to go about this?

Comment: That's why I didn't post my comment as an answer... others will have to help you. :)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I wasn't calling FrameworkDispatcher.Update() before I called MediaPlayer.Pause(). But this is possible to do if your app requires it.